# Banknote is faded

Tags: texturing, shaders, lighting

I am modelling a slim wallet with some bank notes on the back.
Unfortunately, when I light the scene the bank note loses the color and looks faded.

I reduced the lights to a minimum but that didn't really help.

Without the Principled Shader it looks good but unreal because the shadows are missing.

Has someone an idea what I can do to make the colors more pop out?
Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: You could always add some saturation, but is the result really so far off if you looked at a real bill?

Comment: You should also check what color space the image is in

Comment: Did you try to increase the Roughness value?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *Standard* View transform instead of *Filmic*:

[image]

Comment: I would advise against using the standard view transform (sRGB OETF). Instead either use Filmic with a "look" that has an increased contrast and/or perform proper color grading in the compositor. Although adjustments to the material could also be necessary.